# How to run a SyncBack profile with custom source and destination folders?

Tags: file, directory, synchronization, syncback

I am using SyncBackSE to synchronize folders between two locations. Since the full sync takes too long, I want to run the sync profile only for the specified source and destination folders via the command line. Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Command Line Parameters" section of the help file lists all the command line parameters. In that you'll see there are -source and -dest command line parameters to define the source and destination folders.

The actual command goes something like this...

```
SyncBackSE.exe -source "C:\Source\Folder\Path" -dest "C:\Dest\Folder\Path" -m "ProfileToRun"
```

See [this support ticket](http://www.2brightsparks.com/help/index.php?action=ticket&id=NjYyNi02MDE1MDcyMjAz&ide=aW1yYW4uc2hhaGlkQHBvbHljb20uY29t).